# Sum and Group Salary by fortnight

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having some problems summing and grouping a payroll by fortnight. I want to be able to sum all the pay from the 1st-15th and from the 16th to EndofMonth displayed in one query.

I know that this can be done using a UNION query but the UNION query displays the total salary into 2 separate columns I only want one column for the sum of salaries.

Current `UNION` Query:

```
SELECT EOM([wkd]) AS MonthEnding, D.EMPID, Sum(D.YTDWk1) AS TotalYTDF1, Sum(D.YTDWk2) AS TotalYTDF2
FROM (SELECT EMPID, wkd, SumOfGross AS YTDWk1, 0 AS YTDWk2
FROM qryYTDWK1
UNION
SELECT EMPID, wkd, 0, SumOfGross
FROM qryYTDWK2)  AS D LEFT JOIN tblEmp ON D.EMPID = tblEmp.EMPID
GROUP BY EOM([wkd]), D.EMPID
ORDER BY D.EMPID;
```

Returns the following results:

```
+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| EMPID | MonthEnding | Fortnight1 | Fortnight2 |
+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
|     1 | 8/31/19     |       6000 |       2000 |
|     4 | 9/30/19     |       5000 |       3000 |
+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Expected Results:

```
+-------+-----------------+-------+
| EMPID | FortnightEnding | Gross |
+-------+-----------------+-------+
|     1 | 8/15/19         |  6000 |
|     1 | 8/31/19         |  2000 |
|     4 | 9/15/19         |  5000 |
|     4 | 9/30/19         |  3000 |
+-------+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: Why do you have your data across two tables instead of just one?

Comment: It is only one. tblPayroll is the only table for the initial entry but two queries that split it into the 2 fortnights, One from the 1-15th and another from the 16th to MonthEnd.

Comment: I clearly see `FROM` followed by two different tables.

Comment: ``SELECT EOM([wkd]) AS MonthEnding, D.EMPID, Sum(D.YTDWk1) AS TotalYTDF1, Sum(D.YTDWk2) AS TotalYTDF2`` is missing from the start of the sql

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    EMPID, 
    Month([wkd]),
    Sum(IIf(Day([wkd]) < 16, [Salary], 0)) As YTDWk1,
    Sum(IIf(Day([wkd]) < 16, 0, [Salary])) As YTDWk2
FROM 
    YourTable
GROUP BY 
    EMPID,
    Month([wkd])
```

**Edit**: One column:

```sql
SELECT 
    EMPID, 
    Year([wkd]) & "-" & Month([wkd]) & "-" & IIf(Day([wkd]) < 16, 16, DateSerial(Year([wkd]), Month([wkd]) + 1, 0)) As FortnightEnding,
    Sum([Salary]) As Gross
FROM 
    YourTable
GROUP BY 
    EMPID,
    Year([wkd]) & "-" & Month([wkd]) & "-" & IIf(Day([wkd]) < 16, 16, DateSerial(Year([wkd]), Month([wkd]) + 1, 0))
```

Comment: That would give me the same results as my union query. I want all the salaries in one column separated by the period. See _Expected Results:_

Answer (score 0):

You can decide which half of the month in which the date falls using the [`day`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/day-function-6c7fa9a6-15e6-4e64-b45a-01e9338b9415) function and branch accordingly using the [`iif`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) function, e.g.:

```
iif(day(wkd)<16, <first half of month>, <second half of month>)
```

You then need to calculate the appropriate dates corresponding to `<first half of month>` and `<second half of month>` in the above expression.

For this, I would personally use the [`dateserial`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) function.

The end of the first half of the month (i.e. day 15) could be calculated using:

```
dateserial(year(wkd), month(wkd), 15)
```

The end of the second half of the month (i.e. the last day of the month) could be calculated using:

```
dateserial(year(wkd), month(wkd)+1, 0)
```

That is, the 0<sup>th</sup> day of the following month. The [`dateserial`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dateserial-function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) function is very useful in that it will always calculate a valid date from the supplied parameters - hence, if `year(wkd) = 2019` & `month(wkd)+1 = 13`, then rather than returning an error because the month number is greater than 12, `dateserial(2019, 13, 0)` will return 31st December 2019, as expected.

Putting the above together, we have the `FortnightEnding` field:

```
iif
(
    day(wkd)<16,
    dateserial(year(wkd),month(wkd),15), 
    dateserial(year(wkd),month(wkd)+1,0)
) as FortnightEnding
```

And so we can construct the following SQL:

```
select
    empid,
    iif
    (
        day(wkd)<16,
        dateserial(year(wkd),month(wkd),15), 
        dateserial(year(wkd),month(wkd)+1,0)
    ) as FortnightEnding,
    sum(gross)
from
    tblpayroll
group by
    empid,
    iif
    (
        day(wkd)<16,
        dateserial(year(wkd),month(wkd),15), 
        dateserial(year(wkd),month(wkd)+1,0)
    )
```

Grouping by the same calculation results in a summation of the `gross` field for all dates which fall in each group.

If you didn't want to repeat the calculation statement, you could calculate the grouping in a subquery and aggregate the results in the parent query, e.g.:

```
select t.empid, t.FortnightEnding, sum(t.gross)
from
(
    select
        empid,
        iif
        (
            day(wkd)<16,
            dateserial(year(wkd),month(wkd),15), 
            dateserial(year(wkd),month(wkd)+1,0)
        ) as FortnightEnding,
        gross
    from
        tblpayroll
) t
group by t.empid, t.FortnightEnding
```

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!